# Why in the product notation, if the top value is less than the bottom one, the product results to $1$?

Tags: notation, products, index-notation

As an example, for any one dimensional real valued function $f$, if $q<k$ then $\prod_{i=k}^q f(i)=1$. I thought it was $0$ and that was breaking my intuition about some formulas I'm working with. This makes much more sense. Why is this true? Has the fact that the zeroth power of any real number equals one has anything to do with this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product

Comment: $x^n = \prod_{i=1}^nx$, so, yes, this is closely related to the convention that $x^0 = 1$.

Comment: 1, not 0, is the multiplicative identity.  If the empty product were $0$ then all products, by induction you have to be $0$ because $0\times\text{the first thing} = 0$.  But $1 \times \text{the first thing} = \text{the first thing}$.  ... That said I'm not sure your classification of what $\prod_{i=k}^q$ with $q < k$ means  is actually correct.

Comment: Ultimately, it is just a convention. It is a convention we chose to follow for the reasons fleablood and Rob Arthan gave, but it is still simply a choice.